# Find nearest float in array

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, arrays, ipad

How would I get the nearest float in my array to a float of my choice? Here is my array:

```
[1.20, 1.50, 1.75, 1.95, 2.10]
```

For example, if my float was `1.60`, I would like to produce the float `1.50`.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Loop on all the elements of your array find the nearest one.

Comment: Could you write code to do it? Or maybe first define an interface, create a spec of two or three lines what the code implementing the interface will achieve, and then writing the code? And maybe add a few unit tests?

Answer (score 2):

You can do it by sorting the array and finding the nearest one.

For this you can use sortDescriptors and then your algorithm will go.

Even you can loop through, by assuming first as the required value and store the minimum absolute (`abs()`) difference, if next difference is lesser than hold that value.

The working sample, however you need to handle other conditions like two similar values or your value is just between two value like 2 lies between 1 and 3.

```
NSArray *array = @[@1.20, @1.50, @1.75, @1.95, @2.10];

double my = 1.7;
NSNumber *nearest = array[0];

double diff = fabs(my - [array[0] doubleValue]);
for (NSNumber *num in array) {
    double d = [num doubleValue];
    if (diff > fabs(my - d) ) {
        nearest = num;
        diff = my - d;
    }
}

NSLog(@"%@", nearest);
```